# How to generate llvm ir binary(.bc) while compiling project with Bazel?

Tags: llvm, bazel

I am currently trying to compiling tensorflow c standalone library to llvm ir binary format with Bazel. But the Bazel dose not have the same parameters like clang, what should I do if I want to emit llvm binary format using Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3566, it's possible, but not very simple. You would need to write your own CROSSTOOL that will use clang to produce the .bc files, and llvm-link for linking. File extensions are not yet customizable in the CROSSTOOL, so you will have to work with .o and .a.

Some resources to get you started:

- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/About-the-CROSSTOOL
- https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/wiki/Building-with-a-custom-toolchain
- https://bazel.build/designs/2016/02/16/cpp-autoconf.html

Feel free to ask more if you get stuck/lost.

Comment: I see some of those sub-tasks set elf based "shared object" as output file type, if I wanna compile those source code into ".bc", should I revise all thos e sub-tasks and play with those .o and .a files all by myself? I mean re-write all related BUILD files with new compiling logic?

Comment: Note I have no much experience with llvm bitcode, so take my advice with a grain of salt like from somebody who did just a few google searches. In general, I would say you might get away with just using llvm-link for both static and shared libraries, so that at the end you get your libtensorflow.so that is actually a bitcode file. So ideally no BUILD files need to be modified. Note that BUILD files contain very little "compiling logic", the actual compiler/linker invocation is generated using CROSSTOOL. There can be some additional flags added from BUILD files (such as copts attributes).

Comment: I would also start with CROSSTOOL that doesn't invoke llvm tools directly, but goes through the wrapper scripts. In these scripts I would filter out flags that I'm not prepared to handle just yet (or ever). This way you might be able to start small and iterate.

Comment: I am now confusing on how to fill out those fields in CROSSTOOL: all_files\ compiler_files\ linker_files\ objcopy_files and strip_fields.

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/Becavalier/Eufa/blob/master/src/tensorflow/bazel/, wish for your help, thanks!

Comment: cc_toolchain rule is there mainly to collect all the inputs the toolchain depends on. This doesn't include files that you access using absolute path, such as "/home/hbucher/install/include/", only the tools that are stored relative to the crosstool, or tools that are built by bazel and that bazel then uses to build other targets (e.g. imagine the compiler itself was a cc_binary managed by bazel). You don't have to think about the differences between compiler_files and linker_files right now, it's just a optimization. It's completely fine to put all the tools to all these fields.